# Need A SFU that does not decrypt or change data in the rtp and rtcp

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, kurento, turn, mediasoup

I am building an application with gstreamer-webrtc  in which timestramp in RTCP and RTP is curcial .
while using a mediaserver SFU (mediasoup) the media server consumes and consumes/terminates and produces its own RTCP packets.
https://mediasoup.discourse.group/t/forwarding-ntp-timestamp-from-source/3427/4?u=usama.
I need the original RTCP packets. is there any other SFU that does not consumes/terminates the RTCP and just relay it

Comment: Do you want the RTP+RTCP packets forwarded to multiple receivers or just one? Do you care about the RTCP packets coming back to the sender (congestion control etc...)?

Comment: yes I want it for multiple receivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built something similar with Pion, see [broadcast](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/broadcast/main.go). One WebRTC Peer uploads RTP, and then it is fanned out to all the other peers unmodified.

You can do the same with RTCP see [rtcp-processing](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/rtcp-processing/main.go). Accept the incoming RTCP packets and then write to all connected receivers.

If you want to put code up on GitHub happy to help with any specific API questions!